# Facebook developer getting started

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I realize this may be OT, since I don't yet have any code to show.

I am tasked with putting a Facebook login on our website. I am trying to follow this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.4
but I have no where to turn for guidance.

I've tried joining the FB developer's group, but my 'Join' request has simply shown 'pending' for the last few days. I'm not even sure it's active anymore. I read somewhere they've moved here to SE.

Anyway, the current technical problem is a cross domain error, the moment it hits this line:

```
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
```

*Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.*

I kind of expect a cross-domain error, so I don't know what FB is intending here.

But mostly, I'd like assistance in finding their community.

Comment: Call that code from js, don't actually embed it in the DOM. Perform a redirect on the click event. You'll probably have more luck doing it that way, and you will probably also need to handle callbacks.

Comment: Those two lines of code are in the js. You can see them in the inset of the tutorial I linked to. In MY code, those script blocks are in an external .js.

Comment: That is not an actual “cross domain error” – you just need to configure your app properly. Fill in the fields it mentions (the ones that are applicable for your chosen platform), and fill out the relevant fields under Settings->Advanced as well (specifically “Valid OAuth redirect URIs”.)

Comment: Thx @CBroe. I see it now. My App Domains (i.e. developers.facebook.com/apps/{myAppid}/settings/) need to be config'd to point to my domain.